# Images with gradient poorly managed by Unity

Tags: image, graphics, unity-game-engine, transparency, gradient

I'm currently creating a 2D game on Unity and I have a problem with images with gradients or transparency. Here for example, the beginning of one of my levels before importing it in Unity (PNG-8):
[image]

Here when the image is imported into Unity:
[image]

We can see that the gradation is very poorly managed by Unity. What are the ways to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with the image compression settings of the image in Unity? 
Usually, I see that sort of gradient display when my images are set to use the 16bits setting. 
 
If you go on the image in Unity's project tab and you will find *"Format"* in the Inspector tab. You can play around with it and see if any of the other settings will improve the quality.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is bad with 2D texture. You have 2 choice:

1 - Change the Format of the texture to True Color (Result will be as you wish but the size could increase by 4 so it can choke the CPU if it's for a mobile game, I don't recommend it)

2 - Use Crunch Compression to 100%, the result will be the same as the original image but the compression could take a very long time depending on the resolution of the image and if it's a POT.